# How one can write a trigger function?

Tags: python, triggers

I know(from seeing how it works) this is a trigger callback function, due to changing the value.

### Questions:

1. How can I write a custom one(for a custom class/instance)?
2. What is the meaning of the first line(what is that `@` is for?)?

```
@vehicle.on_attribute('last_heartbeat')
def listener(self, attr_name, value):
    global runable
    if value > 1 and not runable: runable = False;
    if value < 1 and runable: runable = True;
```

Comment: 1. I'm not sure what `trigger callback function` is. Never heard of one, but maybe it's just me. Or maybe you mean the `decorators`
2. `@` is used for decorators. You can read about it here: https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecorators They basically wrap your function and run before your function does.